# Android onKeyListener on EditText only responds to "Enter" key when pressed twice

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener

I have an EditText that I want to respond to a user pressing the "Enter" key. Here is the relevant code:

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_query);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
            sendMessage(v);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
    });
```

When I run this on my tablet (Toshiba Thrive), it works perfectly. However, on my phone (HTC Desire HD), the OnKeyListener doesn't fire at all when the "Enter" key is pressed... but works when "Enter" is pressed a second time. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I want implement the realisaI too want implement the realisation of my application that hide my soft keybord at first enter pressure too. You can change this option in settings of you keyboard. (c)It is not bug, it's feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With autocorrect on the phone, pressing "Enter" once selects the suggested spelling of the word. Pressing "Enter" the second time sends the key press to the app. It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Of the 1000+ things that don't work as expected in Android, it's always supposedly "a feature, not a bug".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an AVD for your device(the Desire HD) and seeing if the problem occurs there, too? Your code seems find to me

Comment: No I haven't... How would that help?